How to parse javascript file like deleted-tweets.js to retrieve tweets
I have a 'deleted_tweets.js' file from my Twitter archive, but I'm having difficulty locating specific tweets within the file. The tweets are encoded in JavaScript, and I'm struggling to parse through the data effectively on my phone. Can anyone offer guidance or suggestions on how to search for and retrieve my deleted tweets from this file? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Im trying to find my deleted tweets in deleted-tweets.js file is there any chance that i could covert the data in to page like form like similar to Twitter so I can view the full text tweets with attached pics, videos, and the date and time of the creation of the tweets in ascending in order. Or if possible if i can retrieve my deleted tweets from "deleted-tweetd.js file please

Post your file.

Is deleted_tweets.js actually a javascript file or is it a json file that you might be able to load with json.load() (in python)?
